# Django Admin - saving data from custom form

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to customize the admin panel added to the model page related inputs from another model​​. But I can not figure out how to save them.

admin.py

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'admin/testapp/order/change_form.html'

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        order = Order.objects.get(id=object_id)
        card_list = Card.objects.all().filter(type=order.type)
        result = super(OrderAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context={
        'card_list': card_list,
        })
        return result
```

change_form.html

```
    {% for card in card_list %}
    <input type="text" name="card-{{ card.id}}" value="{{ card.qty }}"></td>
    {% endfor %}
```

How to save the changed values ​​in the Card model?

I tried to do as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin

But self.cleaned_data does not include my data from inputs.

Thanks.

UPD: Well, I caught the data, but I think it's pretty messy way. 
I'm hardly can imagine how I would calculate the id from inputs.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        request.POST['card-288']
```

Comment: This is why you use django forms. If you generated a formset, you could call formset(request.POST).save() and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Saving should be done in [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model). Your `card_list` data <strike>should also be</strike> would have been available in the `form` parameter if you had used django forms. Although you could still access it through `request` as you correctly pointed out.

You will also have to sanitize the data yourself, something that django forms does for your automatically.

Comment: The same result. Only Order model data.  `def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print form`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exactly what you produced :), nothing unexpected there!

You must override `clean` (take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for instance) if you want some fields that you manually added in the change_list to be taken care of.

If you go that way, to retrieve the ID is up to you, but a simple `split('-')[-1]` would work.

This answers your specific need.

On the other side, I think your are not going the right way. The django admin is good enough to deal with ForeignKeys ManyToMany, so I see no need to do things yourself.

While you can get it working with the above hint, I suggest you start all over - if you want, a new SO question where you publish the initial Model and what exactly you are trying to achieve.